# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.RegisteredTFSConnections.GetConfigurationServers() Returns nothing

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have 2 separate applications. One is a Windows Application running in .NET 3.5 and the other is running ASP.NET MVC in .NET 4.5 both in VB.NET. In the 3.5 app, I call .GetConfigurationServers() and get values back for the servers that I am connected to. In the same instance of VS 2012 I run the 4.5 web app and .GetConfigurationServers() returns nothing. I have 0 errors, all the references are the same and I have provided the proper Imports. What other settings am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't Comment :\ Do you know the name of the TFS server you are trying to connect to?

`RegisteredTfsConnections.GetConfigurationServer(serverName)`